# Monero GUI Freezes when Creating New Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet, download

I’ve downloaded the most current version of Monero GUI. When I’m going through the prompts, the program freezes every time I select “Create a new wallet.” It happens even in the low graphics mode. Anyone able to advise what’s happening? I have 224 GB of free space and running a SSD. Is it freezing because the blockchain is being downloaded (using advanced mode)? I’m not sure how to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes many have had problems with Monero-gui-wallet.

Use instead this wallet.
https://featherwallet.org/